# WP7 Mango: How do I delete a live tile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I'm creating a live tile on the device with the following code:

```
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
StandardTileData newTileData = new StandardTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri(string.Format("isostore:{0}", DefaultLiveTilePath), UriKind.Absolute),
    Title = "Test"
};
tile.Update(newTileData);
```

At a later point I would like to delete the live tile image and have it revert to the app icon when pinned.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just use the same code to restore the original image? After all, the original is packaged with your app.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I'm also using the Back image and content of the tile.  When I restore the original image I don't want it to flip over.  Setting the back content and backbackgroundimage to null doesn't do the trick either so I thought it would be best to see if there's a way to delete my tile altogether.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573806/mango-application-tile-remove-back do not the trick?

Comment: Since you can't remove a Tile from code, Ralf Ehlert's answer is the way to do it. Ralf should add his comment as a answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [blog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/16/working-with-live-tiles-in-wp7-mango-creating-updating-and-deleting-them.aspx) you shoudl use this code

```
public void DeleteExistingTile()  
{  
    var foundTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("DetailId=123"));  

    // If the Tile was found, then delete it.  
    if (foundTile != null)  
    {  
        foundTile.Delete();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: That code shows how to delete a secondary tile not how to reset the app's primary tile.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following code when resetting my tile back to normal everytime the app starts:

```
    private void ResetLiveTileToNormal()
    {
        ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();


        ShellTileData shellData = new StandardTileData
        {
            Title = "XXXXXXXX",
            Count = 0,
            BackContent = "",
            BackTitle = "",
            BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
            BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"/Images/LiveTiles/XXXXXX.png", UriKind.Relative)
        };
        TileToFind.Update(shellData);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();` is obsolete.

```
void clearTile() {

            ShellTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                Title = "",
                Count = 0,
                BackContent = "",
                BackTitle = "",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
                BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative)
            };
            IEnumerator<ShellTile> it = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.GetEnumerator();
            it.MoveNext();
            ShellTile tile = it.Current;
            tile.Update(tileData);
        }
```

Based on research and thanks to robertftw