# Remove Live Tile functionality from main Application Tile

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating an app which has the ability for the user to pin a location to their homescreen, and works well using a regular `StandardTileData`.

However, I have currently set it up where if the user hasn't pinned the tile, then the main application tile is changed to be the live tile instead.

However, when the event expires, or the user decides to pin the tile, I want to clear out the main application tile back to default.

With the code below, the exception `0x81030112` happens on the Delete().

Is this possible? Or should I just not update the main app tile. Either your UX feedback / technical solution is appreciated.

```
private void ResetMainTile()
        {
            try
            {
                ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.ToString();
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "live tile" you mean removing the number from the front and back details, then this previous answer seems to solve the issue:

> [Mango Application Tile - remove back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573806/mango-application-tile-remove-back)

If not, please clarify.

Comment: That looks like it, thanks! I spent way too long tonight searching for it ;) much appreciated.